# Can't get UDP Multicasting to work with other computers over home wifi

Tags: java, sockets, ip

I followed the tutorial from [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html) with multicasting UDP, but now i'm confused whether it is supposed to be detectable from other devices on the same WIFi. I run the server on my stationary computer and then i try to execute the client side from my laptop.

Question is: Can i detect the server from my laptop (the client) when they are on the same WIFI? And what are possible reasons for why it does not work? I have the exact code oracle provided.

Comment: Um, okay. Did you have a question?

Comment: @bradimus see edit :)

Comment: Have you seen this question?  It seems similar:
http://superuser.com/questions/730288/why-do-some-wifi-routers-block-multicast-packets-going-from-wired-to-wireless

Comment: IT WORKS - i found my problem :D